# Proving an induced operator norm equality:

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

The induced matrix norm is defined by

$$||A|| = \sup_{x \ne 0} \frac {||Ax||}{||x||} $$

Show that $$||A|| = \sup_{||x||=1} ||Ax||$$

A is only assumed to be square -- not anything more, e.g., not symmetric / orthogonal, etc.

I've been working on this problem for awhile and would welcome any hints.

I've tried using the definition of vector norms, namely ||x|| = $\sqrt{<x,x>}$, and ||Ax|| = $\sqrt{<Ax,Ax>}$, and also using the defintion of adjoint to get ||Ax|| = $\sqrt{<x,A^tAx>}$ and then moving some factors around, using the transpose.  But now I seem to be going in circles.

And it is a little puzzling to go from taking a supremum over all non-vectors to taking a supremum over all *unit* vectors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually only need to use the property that $\|\lambda (Ax)\| = |\lambda|\|Ax\|$

Then, take any $x\neq 0$, and you know that $x = \|x\|\cdot \frac{x}{\|x\|}$, where the norm of $\frac x{\|x\|}$ is $1$.

Using these two facts, you can prove that the sets $$S_1=\{\|Ax\| | \|x\|= 1\}\\S_2 = \{\frac{\|Ax\|}{\|x\|}| x\neq 0\}$$
are the same set.

Comment: Hi @5xum, thanks so much for your answer.  Using the two facts you gave, I went through the algebra and have my solution, but my last equation seems a little suspicious:  after cancellations, I have that $sup_{x \ne 0} ||A(\frac {x}{||x||})||$ =  $sup_{||x||=1} ||A(x)||$.  Is this last step ok?  Thanks,

Comment: (Perhaps I should be using different labeling -- labeling the variable on the right-hand side with "y".)

Comment: Yes, I think I am fine -- I also see now that the answer given by Subhasish Basak does this too.  Thanks for your help @5xum.

Comment: @LebronJames Yup, you are correct.

Answer (score 2):

$x \neq 0$ $\implies y=x/||x||$ has $||y||=1$.
So $||Ax||/||x||=||(Ax/||x||)||=||A(x/||x||)||=||Ay||$ when $x \neq 0$. (as $cAx=Acx$ when $c$ is a constant)

So $sup_{x \ne 0} ||Ax||/||x||=sup_{||y||=1}||Ay||$.

Comment: Thanks so much @SubhasishBasak.